# robot_arm not moving in Moveit but is moving in Gazebo

Tags: ros, moveit, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI! everyone!
I have a robot model,and i want to get the joint_trajectory form moveit!,I use the Gazebo to publish the arm controller.
Everything looks good,but When i set the goal and use plan and excute.Robot_arm not moving in Moveit but is working in Gazebo.

I think it is the problem about the topic /joint state did not receive anything.But I have another topic named robot/joint state published by  arm controller or gazebo.
I already saw the [same problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/223552/model-not-moving-in-rviz-but-is-moving-in-gazebo/)
but i still did not know how to solve this problem.

There have another problem after moveit compute the trajectory.
Moveit always showed the warning :
Controller /utlr_arm_controller failed with error code GOAL_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED
Controller handle utl/r_arm_controller reports status ABORTED

In some articles tell me add the `<param name="allowed_goal_duration_margin" value="5.0"/>`,but it did not work!

Please help me to solve these two problems! and thanks for any help! I can provide any file you need to check!
attach is the picture about the problem:[picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02FisAlf-IXajNsN0RDSEd0Qkk/view?usp=sharing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246960/robot_arm-not-moving-in-moveit-but-is-moving-in-gazebo/) by [Josephlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26881/josephlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remapic the topic /joint_states to /robot/joint_states in move_group.launch, inside the move_group node. I had this same problem as well and this worked just fine for me. You will need to change back to /joint_states though when running MoveIt! without the Gazebo simulation.

As for the other error, I just ignore it since the end position is nearly identical to the MoveIt! trajectory goal. Forgot where in the MoveIt! Google groups this was mentioned, but I looked into it as well.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josephlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26881/josephlin/) on 2016-11-02**:
Thank you very much! I also solve the problem too! If you have the any idea or answer about GOAL_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED. Please let me know! you can add a comment in this Question! or send the email.

**Comment by [Deastan](https://answers.ros.org/users/38671/deastan/) on 2019-07-08**:
Did you find a solution for GOAL_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED?